# Find height of a tree without using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I want you to pick my code apart and give me some feedback on how I could make it better or simpler.

```
public int heightHelper(TreeNode node) {
    int height = -1;

    if (node == null) return height;

    final Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    queue.add(node);

    int currentLevelNodeCount = 1;
    int nextLevelNodeCount = 0;

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode current = queue.poll();
        currentLevelNodeCount--;

        if (current.left != null) { queue.add(current.left); nextLevelNodeCount++; }

        if (current.right != null)  { queue.add(current.right);  nextLevelNodeCount++; }

        // current level is done.
        if (currentLevelNodeCount == 0) {
            height++;
            currentLevelNodeCount = nextLevelNodeCount;
            nextLevelNodeCount = 0;
        }
    }
    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is basically sound.

It's not a helper function, so don't name it as such.  (Helper functions would usually be `private`.)

Comments would be good.  In particular, a JavaDoc explaining how to interpret the height of a degenerate tree would be helpful.

Your `currentLevelNodeCount` and `nextLevelNodeCount` are basically segmenting the queue into two queues the hard way.  Why not reduce the bookkeeping by using two queues?  (I've named them `thisLevel` and `nextLevel` because variable names that have the same length make the code look pretty.)

A few tweaks here and there make the code slightly more compact.

```
/**
 * Returns the maximum depth of a tree.
 *
 * @param node The root of the tree
 *
 * @return -1 if node is null, 0 if node has no children,
 *         a positive number otherwise.
 */
public int height(TreeNode node) {
    int height = -1;
    if (node != null) {
        // Breadth-first traversal, keeping track of the number of levels
        Queue<TreeNode> thisLevel = new LinkedList<TreeNode>(),
                        nextLevel = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();

        thisLevel.add(node);
        while (null != (node = thisLevel.poll())) {
            if (node.left  != null) nextLevel.add(node.left);
            if (node.right != null) nextLevel.add(node.right);

            if (thisLevel.isEmpty()) {
                height++;

                Queue<TreeNode> swapTemp = thisLevel;
                thisLevel = nextLevel;
                // We could create a new nextLevel queue, but reusing the
                // newly emptied thisLevel queue is more efficient.
                nextLevel = swapTemp;
            }
        }
    }
    return height;
}
```

Comment: perfectly agreed, i hope some crazy interviewer does not see `2 data structures used` as a disadvantage. It happens.

Comment: i do accept your code as a better answer, but for `sake of interviews` stick with 2 counters.

Comment: In almost all circumstances, priorities should be 1) bug-free, 2) easy to understand and maintain, and 3) efficient. An interviewer who insists on prioritizing (3) over (1) and (2) should be a red flag. They may be interviewing you as a candidate, but remember, you're evaluating them too as a potential employer.

Comment: @200_success well done. This code is really easy to understand.